# Checking a ring is not Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, cohen-macaulay

While reading a book, I found an example that said that the ring $K[w,x,y,z]/(wy,wz,xy,xz)$ is not Cohen-Macaulay. In order to check this, it is stated to take the quotient by the ideal generated by the non-zero divisor $w-y$, that gives the ring $K[x,y,z]/(y^2,yz,xy,xz)$. The book assures that all the elements of *its maximal ideal are zero divisors*.

I couldn't follow through this last part: I don't see why this ring would be local (do I need to localize in a maximal ideal?)

You can find this section of the pdf file by looking up "25. Regular local rings Corollary 25.1".

Comment: Could you also provide the citation for the book?  It's silly to mention it without telling us what it is. It could make a difference in deciding if there's an errata or not.

Comment: You're right, I just added it.

Answer (score 3):

If it were local, all its quotients would be local, but factoring out by the ideal generated by $y$ and $z$, you get $K[x]$, which isn't local.

Secondly, the minimal primes of the second quotient are pretty clearly the ideals $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$, quotienting by them we get $K[z]$ and $K[x]$ respectively, so it becomes clear that among the maximal ideals there are $(x,y,p(z))$ and $(p(x), y, z)$, where the $p$ represents an irreducible polynomial.

It isn't clear to me how $x-1$ would be a zero divisor in $(x-1,y,z)$ in the second quotient.

That doesn't completely rule out that the example isn't Cohen-Macaulay, though, only that the hint appears to have problems. Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with Cohen-Macaulay rings and can't tell you straightaway. Perhaps if you provide more info about the work this appeared in.

Comment: Here's the [DaRT query for non-Cohen-Macauley](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&L=117) rings, if you still need examples.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier argument with minimal primes was mistaken, as I realized.

Comment: I disagree that the hint has problems: the given ring is graded local, so everything works as expected. Particularly, the ring is Cohen-Macaulay if and only if its completion (with respect to the unique homogeneous maximal ideal) is Cohen-Macaulay. One can see that $k[[w, x, y, z]] / (wy, wz, xy, xz)$ is local in the usual sense, so we can just work with that, if it's more comfortable.

Comment: @Carlo That's probably the case, but just from the (very thin) context given I can see why the user is puzzled.  Do you disagree with either of the things I thought I determined (that the second quotient isn't local, and that its maximal ideals do not consist entirely of zero divisors)?  It would be a completely different story if the hint intended for us to be checking a ring other than that one.

Comment: I agree that there exist maximal ideals that do not consist of zero divisors (as you have illustrated), but I believe that the unique homogeneous maximal ideal consists of zero divisors. But yes, the second quotient is not local; rather, it is graded local.

Comment: @Carlo OK, excellent. I'm sure your understanding of how to solve the problem is better than mine, so you have my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $(wy, wz, xy, xz) = (w, x) \cap (y, z),$ hence the height of $(wy, wz, xy, xz)$ is $2.$ We have therefore that $R = k[w, x, y, z] / (wy, wz, xy, xz)$ has dimension $2.$ On the other hand, the element $w - y$ is neither a zero divisor nor a unit, hence the sequence $(w - y)$ is $R$-regular. Going modulo $(w - y),$ we have that $R / (w - y) \cong k[x, y, z] / (y^2, yz, xy, xz),$ and each of the generators of the unique homogeneous maximal ideal $\mathfrak m = (x, y, z)$ is a zero divisor. Consequently, there are no regular sequences in $R / (w - y),$ hence it follows that $\operatorname{depth} R = 1 < 2 = \dim R$ so that $R$ is not Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: According to my defintion, a ring is called Cohen-Macaulay if each localization by a maximal ideal is Cohen-Macaulay (i.e., depth(R) = dim(R)). However, you seem to use that last condition for _R_, which isn't local. Shouldn't you localize _R/(w_-_y_) by _m_?
Also, how can you check that _w_-_y_ is neither a unit nor a zero divisor?

Comment: Crucially, $R$ is graded local: it is a finitely generated algebra over its degree $0$ piece, and the degree $0$ piece is a local ring in the usual sense. Consequently, we can view $R$ as a local ring with unique (homogeneous) maximal ideal $(w, x, y, z).$ Last, the element $w - y$ of $R$ is not a zero divisor because $(w - y)f = 0$ if and only if $(w - y)f$ is in $(wy, wz, xy, xz) = (w, x) \cap (y, z).$ Use the fact that both ideals in this decomposition are prime.